# ROS Subscriber receives a number of messages larger than the number of messages published by the publisher

Tags: ros, python

I'm using ROS noetic and Python, my node publishes a message if some conditions are met, the queue_size is set to 1.
When I subscribe to the published topic I can see that the subscriber is receiving more messages (even incomplete) than the messages my node is publishing!

How can this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Something might be wrong with your publisher logic or there is another source  publishing to the same topic. The subscriber just reads the data that's published to the topic.

You can check how many publishers and subscribers are on a topic with `rostopic echo <topic>`. More commands [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic).